# ACL and Sonata Admin using inherited entities

Tags: inheritance, acl, sonata-admin

I use inherited entities based on SINGLE_TABLE inheritance type.
I can declare the admin service, setting setSubClasses in my config, as describe in the doc here:
http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/advanced.html#inherited-classes

But I have the following error when creating or deleting:

```
$identifier cannot be empty.
500 Internal Server Error - InvalidDomainObjectException
1 linked Exception: InvalidArgumentException
```

Anyone already experience this?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you. After digging around, I think I may have found the issue.

My set up is similar to the following:

I have a `UserEditableObject` class, which (almost) everything the user can edit extends from. I was getting the `InvalidDomainObjectException` error on my `Page` object, which extends from `UserEditableObject`, and is mapped using `SINGLE_TABLE` inheritance.

I had a `getId()` method in the page, which was calling `Page::id`. When I remove this `getId` method, the error stopped. Please let me know if this fixes your issue as well.